# Is the sample path from Monte Carlo Simulation follows CLT?

Tags: statistics, monte-carlo

I'm pricing some derivative securities with Monte Carlo Simulation.

I don't know population follows which distribution.
But When I some calculation with my samples(all the each path) ,for example $X = ${$X_i | 1≤i≤10,000$ and $i ⊂ N$}, it seems follows normal distribution. I mean $X$~$N(μ,σ^2)$

I know that we can apply Law of Large Numbers to my sample path.
So if the population have mean $a$ and variance $b$ then $X$ have mean $a$ and variance $b/n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (Assume that number of the sample is $n$)

However it doesn't guarantee that the sample paths follows '**normal** 'distribution.

But just seeing the result of my sample path it seems to follow normal distribution.
What makes me confusing is that in my monte carlo simulation the number of sample is just 1 by each sample path!

I mean I don't calculate every new 10,000 paths with 20,000 times. I just get 10,000 paths then averaging once. Then the average value is the price of my derivative security.

I know that CLT gets the power when the $n$ is goes to ∞. Considering just weak version, at least $n > 30$

But I have 10,000 sample paths with each of it constructed with just one! I mean n is 1!

In Short my question is : Does every result sample path from monte carlo simulation follow normal distribution regardless of the number of the sample $n$?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Monte Carlo paths are draws from whatever distribution you are using.  Normal, if that's what you are using.  Of course, any sample is likely to exhibit biases of various sorts.  In Finance, this is especially evident when, say, you are trying to price deep out of the money options.  Even if your sample is pretty good, it might not do a great job at the tails, for example.  I don't know what you mean by saying $n=1$.  You can't price much of anything with a single path.

Comment: @lulu Sorry for confusing. Let's compare with another example. If we conclude how long are the global people, we just investigate with sample using CLT. If n is 10,000 I need to choose 10,000 people randomly then get the average. and I do this job 20,000 times again. Then get the average value of 20,000 average of samples. However In derivative pricing we just get 10,000 sample paths, but we don't do this behavior 20,000 times. We just average this then it's finished. So I think because we don't do this behavior 20,000 times, I can't apply CLT in this context.

Comment: So I think I can't apply CLT. In addition, Law of large numbers doesn't guarantee that samples follows normal distribution. However, my result tells me that it seems to follow normal! Also I don't know population follows which distribution. So I don't know the reason why this result follows normal distribution. Therefore I conclude that it would be my misunderstanding about CLT. So I ask this question.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Perhaps it is a language issue.  "How long are the global people", for example, makes no sense at all.

Comment: Perhaps you are just asking if $10000$ paths is enough, for which the answer is "it depends".  It's certainly fewer than I would use for most applications.  If you are stuck with such a small number, I suggest using pseudo-random numbers rather than strictly random, but I am not at all sure that I have understood your question.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not lived in the country that use English, so I give you confusion. The number 10,000 is just an example. My focus is the reason why Monte Carlo result(I mean sample path) follows normal distribution.

Comment: It does not make sense to ask if one path satisfies a distribution. But again, I fear language issues are making me unable to understand your question.  Good luck!